# Java - JAXB read element value as array without storing its string value

Tags: java, jaxb

I use JAXB to read some sort of password file.

```
<password expiry-date="some date">PASSWORD</password>
```

The requirement is to never store the password value in memory as plain text.

I've written an adapter class to unmarshal the password value as a char array.

```
public class PasswordAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, char[]> {

   @Override
   public String marshal(char[] v) {
      return new String(v);
   }

   @Override
   public char[] unmarshal(String v) {
      return v.toCharArray();
   }
}
```

This is the field that is unmarshalled:

```
@XmlValue
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PasswordAdapter.class)
private char[] password;
```

The problem with this solution is that the password is still read as a string before being stored as an array in this case.

**My Question:**

Is there some way to read the value of the password element directly as an array or just something that is not a plain text string?

Comment: Convert the password to base64 in the XML file (gives `UEFTU1dPUkQ=`) and use `byte[]` type in your Java class - that will represent `xs:base64Binary` data type.

Comment: @lexicore this would be a great idea. Unfortunately we can't do this. The password in the password file has to be plaintext to make it easier for the application support to change / maintain it.

Comment: Well, one has to die one death here. Either you need to avoid plaintext or not.
I'd address this by teaching app support base64 conversion. There are even [online tools](https://www.base64encode.org/) for this.